# Force browser to clean cache in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, browser-cache, cache-control

Trying to use Cache Busting Technique to clear the cache for each release. Used `new Date().getTime()` or `Hash()` method to create a unique version value and append the version value after the file path.

This should apply the version number to the main.js file from the build directory, so I don't have to add the version number to all js and CSS files.

1.

```html
<link style="stylesheet" href={'main.css?v=${value}'}/>
```

2. 

```html
<script src={'main.js?v=${value}'} />
```

Comment: what do you want? I can't understand your question.

Comment: I want to ensure that the browser fetches the latest versions of my static assets(which live in the build directory), so the browser fetches the latest version of those assets instead of relying on cached versions

Comment: Your approach is right. so you mean how to implement this approach?

Comment: I have never done this in React, I wonder if there's any way I can test it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react, you can use third-party library such as `react-cache-buster` for Cache Busting.
This library allows clients to automatically check the new version when a new version is released in the production environment, and if a new version is published, clearing the cache and reload the page.

For example:

```
import React from 'react';
import CacheBuster from 'react-cache-buster';
import { version } from '../package.json';
import Loading from './loading';

const App = () => {
  const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
  return (
    <CacheBuster
      currentVersion={version}
      isEnabled={isProduction} //If false, the library is disabled.
      isVerboseMode={false} //If true, the library writes verbose logs to console.
      loadingComponent={<Loading />} //If not pass, nothing appears at the time of new version check.
      metaFileDirectory={'.'} //If public assets are hosted somewhere other than root on your server.
    >

      // Your actual root component...

    </CacheBuster>
  );
};

export default App;
```

To learn more, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cache-buster

Comment: I getting a proxy issue

Comment: Umm, it's weird. You can delete your package-lock.json and node_modules folder in your project and re-install all dependencies. If not, please let me know. - @darking123

Comment: Yeah, I can try that. Now I kind of confused, if I am using CRA(create-react-app), which supports cache-buster, it automatically generates an optimized production build of our react application, and it creates a unique hash value for the filenames of the generated Javascript and CSS files. (main.js and main.css). What's the change using a third-party library?

Comment: @darking123 - The third-party library has an advantage over the CRA approach. It can detect when your app has a new version and automatically clear the cache and reload the page for your users. With CRA, you only change the filenames of your files when you build your app. But that doesn't guarantee that your users will see the latest version of your app. They might still have to refresh their browser or clear their cache by themselves.